# programmatically close street view

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a map inside an accordion component. I'd like to return the user to the map's default state each time the map is accessed. This is fine unless the user has gone into street view. 
In this case I'd like to close it. Is there a programmatic way to do this?

I've looked around the documentation but have come up empty handed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set the `visible`-property of the streetViewPanorama to false by calling:

```
map.getStreetView().setVisible(false)
```

Comment: Thanks - would have never found that.